# Jest - Could not locate module ./fonts/galio.ttf mapped as

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I'm new to react native testing and recently I got this error. I'm still unable to find a correct solution to fix this. Could you please someone can help on this?

Thanks in advance.

```
Configuration error:

    Could not locate module ./fonts/galio.ttf mapped as:

 Please check your configuration for these entries:
     {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$/": "/Users/iswanjumat/Documents/works/jet_stream_africa/jetpaynow_mobile_app/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified my jest configuration to add this:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
 +     "galio": "identity-obj-proxy"
}
```

And installed the identity-obj-proxy package **npm i identity-obj-proxy** and it solved the font problem.
It seems that the problem was that the font was not recognized, because it doesn't know the extension.

Here's where I found the solution [link](https://github.com/galio-org/galio/issues/187#issuecomment-791872935)